# history of logged users on the same tty

Tags: linux, bash, history, tty

Is there some file, which keeps track about terminal history and users who has been logged to that same terminal?
thanks

Comment: `last <username> | grep <term_name>` comes to mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The file is called "wtmp" and the program which views it is "last". See khachik's comment.